# [UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance SIGABRT

Tags: ios, uiimageview, nsmutablearray, sigabrt

I've got this code trying to run a simple set of images in a cycle. All I have in the app is one UIImageView declared in my View Controller's .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageDisplay;
```

And the following in my .m file's viewDidLoad method:

```
NSMutableArray *imageView = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[imageView addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EyeAnim1.png"]]];
[imageView addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EyeAnim2.png"]]];
[imageView addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EyeAnim3.png"]]];
[imageView addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EyeAnim4.png"]]];
[imageView addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EyeAnim5.png"]]];
[imageView addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EyeAnim6.png"]]];
[imageView addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EyeAnim7.png"]]];

imageDisplay.animationImages = imageView;
imageDisplay.animationDuration = 0.25;
imageDisplay.animationRepeatCount = 50;
[imageDisplay startAnimating];
```

The code seems to be crashing on the "imageDisplay.animationImages" line, as if I create the UIImageView, create its getter and setter, and build, it's fine until I uncomment that line. If I do uncomment it, it keeps giving me the error until I delete the UIImageView and create a new one.

Not too sure what's happening, any help appreciated!

Comment: When you say it crashes, what's the specific error that it crashes out with?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

animationImages array MUST contain only UIImage objects. Your array contains UIImageView objects.

Also your code is unsafe - if one of the resources will not exist app will crash (trying to add nil object to the mutable array). This will be much safer:

```
#define kNumberOfImages 7


NSMutableArray *imageView = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSUInteger i = 1; i <= kNumberOfImages; i++) {
    UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"EyeAnim%d", i]];
    if(anImage) {
        [imageView addObject:anImage];
    }
}

self.imageDisplay.animationImages = imageView;
self.imageDisplay.animationDuration = 0.25;
self.imageDisplay.animationRepeatCount = 50;
[self.imageDisplay startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 17):

I am very new to objective-c and I have been getting this error also, but for a different reason. I just wanted to post my solution for anyone else who may be struggling.

So basically I have a custom class called ImagesDetailViewController which inherits from UIViewController and has an image property.

```
@interface ImagesDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image;
@end
```

I then connected my class to my UIImageView on my storyboard like so

```
@interface ImagesDetailViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@end
```

In my viewDidLoad method I was trying to set the image for my image view like this and getting the error mentioned above (my image variable gets initialised in a prepareForSegue method)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.imageView setImage:self.image];
}
```

So I was stumped as I bet you are all too. The problem had to do with the storyboard. Clicking on my UIImageView and then navigating to the Connections Inspector, I had somehow created 2 referencing outlets (oops...) and one was pointing to a variable called image. So when the program was running [self.imageView setImage:self.image] self.image was actually an instance of UIImageView instead of UIImage.

Comment: Very awful behaviour of xcode.. if you have created an outlet and then you change the variable name, the outlet connection doesn't update automatically. You need to delete the connection and create a new one