# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isResizable] Exception with custom tableview cell

Tags: uitableview, swift

I get a `NSInvalidArgumentException` on execution time off my custom cell.

**The debugger error log:**

`2014-12-25 21:39:11.397 Codebuddies[24159:11353215] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa5f580b6a0'`
`

**The related swift code block:**

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FeedTableViewCell`

**What I've already checked:**

- Identifier of the cell is set to "Cell"

Thanks for help!

Comment: "`UIImage`" has "`isResizable`", while "`UIImageView`" does not have it.  Check to see where "`isResizable`" is called in your code and what kind of object it's called on.  [Also look at potentially very related questions on Stackoverflow, like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610360/uiimageview-isresizable-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-sigabrt).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @MichaelDautermann I was able to fix my problem.

I had deprecated 'Referencing objects' in my inspector view. I removed them and it now works as wished.